Removing specific value from list, Python
I have a list with dictionaries. Each of them contains an object. What is the proper way to remove one specific dictionary, with its object's lowest attribute value?
balls = [{'body': Body(), 'color': (6, 208, 1, 255), 'rad': 10}, ...]

The way I did that:
searcher = balls.copy()
searcher.sort(key=lambda x: x['body'].position[1])
balls.remove(searcher[0])

I wonder if there is faster and more "pythonic" way.

Could you clarify what you mean by "with it's object's lowest attribute value"?

Every object has .position[1] float number. I need an object with the lowest one in the list.

Your problem is the same as finding the min/max of a list. A simple for loop, which temporarily saves the index of the smallest element, is all you need. Don't use the sort function, as it involves a number of operations that are not usefull her.

You can use min with a key function.

x = min(balls, key=(the same)); balls.remove(x)

You say you want to remove the element with "lowest" value, but with reverse=True, the first element will be the one with the highest value.

Pasted wrong code accidently.

To remove the dictionary with the lowest 'body.position[1]' value from the list, you can use min:
min_dict = min(balls, key=lambda x: x['body'].position[1])
balls.remove(min_dict)


Thanks! that's what I was searching for. I only saw key functions with sort and used it everywhere.
